# CSS Mask Animation Looking Very Jittery

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm looking to create an effect with CSS masking where the masked image moves very slowly while the mask shape remains static. Right now I'm doing it with opposite animations, but as you can see it's looking very jittery... Any ideas or suggestions are much appreciated! I am not opposed to a non-CSS-only solution either.

HTML:

```
<div class="masked-section">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486903658356-4006b8abd767?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=178c7b6760bd80795174675611b673c1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80" class="mask"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.masked-section {
  height: 800px;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1420768255295-e871cbf6eb81?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=fecaea6c506b84475edf1e4164944c38&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80);
  background-size: cover;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.mask {
  mask-image: url(https://www.webascender.com/Portals/0/Blog/SVG-101/apple.svg);
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://www.webascender.com/Portals/0/Blog/SVG-101/apple.svg);
  display: block;
  width: 120vw;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  mask-mode: alpha;
  -webkit-mask-mode: alpha;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-size: 15%;
  -webkit-mask-size: 15%;
  mask-position: 31vw 150px, center;
  -webkit-mask-position: 31vw 150px, center;
  animation: test 100s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes test {
  25% { transform: translate(-31vw, -150px); mask-position: 62vw 300px, center; -webkit-mask-position: 62vw 300px, center }
  50% { transform: translate(0, 0); mask-position: 31vw 150px, center; -webkit-mask-position: 31vw 150px, center;}
  75% { transform: translate(-31vw, -150px); mask-position: 62vw 300px, center; -webkit-mask-position: 62vw 300px, center; }
}
```

Codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KoPzOM

Comment: Have you considered using `clip-path` on a div containing the image?

Comment: Thank you! The [actual SVG](http://revelandrouse.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/_revel/library/img/RR_Logo.svg) is a logo and I'm having trouble getting it to work. Does this need to be adjusted in order for this method to work @ManuelOtto ? Thanks again!

Comment: I can't access your link, but you basically just have to paste the path data into the `PATH DATA HERE` part of the given example. Compare the svg of the apple logo with the svg of the codepen i posted.

Comment: Shoot you're right, forgot about the authentication... My issue is it's a more complex SVG with a bunch of groups and paths so I'm having a bit of trouble! [Here's an actually accessible link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWxwMQ). @ManuelOtto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `clip-path` on a div containing the image. Apply the transitions to the image inside the div.

To use the `clip-path` you need to craft a svg for that like this:

```
<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath">
      <path d="PATH DATA HERE"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

And place it in the document.

Then link the clip-mask by applying `clip-path: url(#svgPath)` to the div.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VXZKRb

Comment: Hi @Manuel Otto, Do you mind share link again? Link not working, thanks, best